# Office documents are downloaded instead of opened

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I am having an issue with documents such as Word and Excel being downloaded instead of opened via Office when accessed via a direct URL in SP 2013. I might expect this behavior in Chrome or Firefox, but it is also happening in IE 9. In researching, I have have found many discussions about this happening in SP 2010 ([example](https://superuser.com/questions/529916/problems-opening-sharepoint-document-checked-out-but-opening-from-temp-folder)), but it seems like it should just work in 2013. The site is in the Local Intranet zone. The Web Application's "Browser File Handling" settings are "Permissive". Any suggestions?

Edit:
After further testing, I am only able to replicate this with the URL that is sent out via the "Share" feature. The URL appears to be appending "?web=1" presumably telling SP to use the browser to open it. We are not running Office Web Apps and so this flag seems inappropriate. I found someone else describing the [same issue](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/47ebe2eb-5817-4e58-823b-e8a549afff73/change-share-button-email-link-default-behavior-of-opening-in-office-web-app?forum=sharepointgeneral) but the solution provided to modify the SharePoint call outs seemed drastic. SharePoint can't handle this itself?

Edit2:
After additional testing, this issue seems to be isolated to Excel files. Word documents seem to work fine. That is, when I share an Excel file from a document library via the "Share" link, the link contains "?web=1" at the end and users experience the problems described. A Word document shared in the same way from the same library does not have the "?web=1" appended and behaves as expected.

Comment: Are you providing the link to direct URL in some custom page or this problem is while clicking on the document directly from the library?

Comment: which Office version you have, it needs x64 bit version of Office..

Comment: SharePoint does NOT need 64-bit version of Office. In contrary: always use Office 32-bit, unless you explicitly need Excel 64-bit to do massive calculations.

As for your problem: can't you apply the fix from the KB-article? Maybe edit the file, so the registry settings apply to version 15 instead of 12?

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri, I am running Office 32-bit. But as Leon suggests, I can't imagine that this would be an issue. Do you have any information that would suggest otherwise? Thanks.

Comment: @LeonZandman, unfortunately, the suggested KB-article changes are already in place on both the server and my client. I updated the question with some additional information that it appears to only be an issue when the URL contains the "?web=1" query string parameter.

Comment: Check the site/site collection features to see if the Always Open in Browser OR Client feature is enabled (I can't remember which way around it is). There are also settings (rather than features) for this at the web app and document library level...if my memory serves me well. If you can't find anything based on this suggestion, lemme know and I'll have a look on my demo farm tomorrow.

Comment: @AshleySteel, thanks for those suggestions. Unfortunately, it looks like they are all set correctly. On the site collection "Open Documents in Client Applications by Default" is Active. The document library setting for "Opening Documents in the Browser" is set to "User the server default (Open in the client application)".

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you try to use jQuery or JavaScript to replace the string "?web=1" Inside the URL link?